# record video using webcam in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, video-capture

we are developing a web site where you can upload videos about tutorials, it looks like a repository of videos for a certain institution. and we came up a idea where the user can record a video directly to the site and upload it with title,description, etc. . and we are going to use ruby on rails framework. Do anyone knows here how to make it except using flash and silverlight?
 well i search some and found some but the case is when the user stops the recording it automatically upload the file...and the user can put some title or descriptions etc.. and the example is in php thats why its a problem to me also how can i do it in rails

thanks in advance

Comment: could you provide the solution you did please.

Comment: we haven't implement it because it's very hard for us. So we didn't solve this yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an HTML5 solution could be suitable for you, you can take a look to WebRTC (currently supported in Chrome, Firefox and Opera).

You can find a good tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

The first hit on searching `webcam plugin`: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ As it is using JavaScript it is easy to include in Rails.

Many others appear in the results ...

Another option is to use the `Nimbb widget`. There are a lot of tutorials showing how to embed it into a website.

There are list of **JQuery Plugins** for webcam.. Best **Top 10** are listed Below:

### 1. [ScriptCam : jQuery plugin to manipulate Webcams](https://plugins.jquery.com/ScriptCam/)

ScriptCam is a popular JQuery plugin to manipulate webcams. Take snapshots, detect movement, colors, QR and barcodes, record videoclips and organize videochats.

### 2. [Xarg jQuery webcam plugin](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?a3kKtdQq)

The jQuery webcam plugin is a transparent layer to communicate with a camera directly in JavaScript.This plugin provides three different modes to access a webcam through a small API directly with JavaScript – or more precisely jQuery. Thus, it is possible to bring the image on a Canvas (callback mode), to store the image on the server (save mode) and to stream the live image of the Flash element on a Canvas (stream mode).

### 3. [jQuery.WebcamQRCode : QR Code scanning in jQuery](https://github.com/marcbuils/jquery.webcamqrcode)

WebcamQRCode is a jQuery plugin that uses the webcam user to scan a QR code and return the result to Javascript to be treated. This plugin was originally developed to scan the barcode of the product and automatically fill in the corresponding information on the form of an intranet.This plugin uses Flash to access the webcam.

### 4. [Photobooth-js : jQuery Html5 plugin to take pictures through webcam](https://github.com/WolframHempel/photobooth-js)

Photobooth-js is a jQuery plugin plus an html5 widget that allows users to take their avatar pictures on your site.This jquery plugin is supported in all browsers that support navigator.getUserMedia.

### 5. [Photobooth with PHP, jQuery and CSS3](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?htLcYZ9A)

In this tutorial, we will be building a jQuery and PHP powered photobooth. It will allow your website visitors to take a snapshot with their web camera and upload it from a neat CSS3 interface.The solution we are going to use for this app is webcam.js. It is a JavaScript wrapper around flash’s API that gives us control over the user’s webcam.

### 6. [Mackers jQuery Webcam Plugin](https://github.com/mackers/jquery.webcam)

Plugin which allows jQuery to read data from a user’s webcam or other video capture device.

### 7. [headtrackr : Javascript library for headtracking via Webcam](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/)

headtrackr is a javascript library for real-time face tracking and head tracking, tracking the position of a users head in relation to the computer screen, via a web camera and the webRTC/getUserMedia standard.

### 8. [tracking.js : Real Time tracking techniques by the Camera](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js)

The tracking.js brings to web elements tracking techniques of a real scene captured by the camera, through natural interactions from object tracking, color markers, among others, allowing the development of interfaces and games through a simple and intuitive API.

### 9. [Reveal.js with Webcam-based gesture recognition](https://github.com/willy-vvu/reveal.js)

This is what I got when I combined webcam-based gesture recognition with Hakim El Hattab’s reveal.js. It took me a while to write and fine tune the detection algorithms. Even then, the algorithms are only about 80% accurate.

### 10. [Say Chees : JavaScript library for integrating a webcam](https://github.com/leemachin/say-cheese)

A minimal library for integrating webcam snapshots into your app. It uses getUserMedia, a recent API for accessing audio and video in the browser.

If my Answer Satisfied your requirement somehow or somewhere then I appreciate if you **Up-Vote** this **Answer**... :) ;)

Comment: i have encountered about the jquery webcam plugin in xarg and the worst i forgot to view it again.. :D haha btw do you have experience using it the plugin?

Comment: @heathcliff : No I haven't use them yet...Now check my Updated Answer.. ;)

Comment: WebRTC is now only supported over secure connection (https).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any external library and in fact, I think the work is way easier if you build this from the ground up.

You'll first need access to the user's webcam, with JavaScript you can first test if the user has a webcam in the first place. This can be done with:

```
function hasNavigator() {
      return !!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)
    }
```

Then if `hasNavigator()` is `true`, you can

```
if (video) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => { video.srcObject = stream })
      }
```

where `video` is

```
var video = document.querySelector('video')
```

This allows you to fetch a stream from the webcam:

Once you have the stream you can draw a frame of the stream on a canvas and save it as an image.

I wrote a blog post about [Linking a Webcam Directly to Rails' ActiveStorage](https://emmanuelhayford.com/linking-a-webcam-directly-to-rails-activestorage/) that I think you might find helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How would someone go about this?